# Power Shell Windows Service Update dll's process

Tags: c#, shell, dll

I have Power Shell script for publish/update new dll's for running windows service:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

function Main(
[string] $siteName = $(Throw "Value cannot be null: siteName"),
[string] $sitePath = $(Throw "Value cannot be null: sitePath"),
[string] $servicePath = $(Throw "Value cannot be null: sitePath"),
[string] $serviceName = $(Throw "Value cannot be null: sitePath"),
[string] $buildConfiguration = $(Throw "Value cannot be null: sitePath"))
{
...

   $serviceBinPath = Join-Path $serviceBinPath $buildConfiguration
   Write-Host "Directory of Windows Service : $($serviceBinPath )`r`n"

   StopWindowsService $serviceName
   RemoveFiles $servicePath 
   CopyFiles $serviceBinPath $servicePath
   StartWindowsService $serviceName
}

function RemoveFiles(
    [string] $path = $(Throw "Value cannot be null: sitePath"))
{
    If (Test-Path $path)
    {
        Write-Host "Removing folder ($path)...`r`n"
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "$($path)*"
        Write-Host "Successfully removed website folder ($path)...`r`n"        
    }
}

function CopyFiles(
    [string] $sourcePath = $(Throw "Value cannot be null: sitePath"),
    [string] $destinationPath = $(Throw "Value cannot be null: sitePath"))
{
    If ((Test-Path $sourcePath) -and (Test-Path $destinationPath))
    {
        Write-Host "Copy files from ($sourcePath) to folder ($destinationPath)...`r`n"
        Copy-Item "$($sourcePath)\*" $destinationPath -Recurse -Force
        Write-Host "Successfully copied files from ($sourcePath).`r`n"
    }
}
function StopWindowsService(
    [string] $serviceName = $(Throw "Value cannot be null: siteName"))
{
    $serviceBefore = Get-Service $serviceName
    Write-Host "($serviceName) is now ($serviceBefore.status)...`r`n"

    Write-Host "Stopping Windows Service ($serviceName)...`r`n"
    Stop-Service $serviceName
    Write-Host "Successfully stopped Windows Service ($serviceName)...`r`n"

    $serviceAfter = Get-Service $serviceName
    Write-Host "($serviceName) is now ($($serviceAfter.status))...`r`n"
}

function StartWindowsService(
    [string] $serviceName = $(Throw "Value cannot be null: siteName"))
{
    $serviceBefore = Get-Service $serviceName
    Write-Host "($serviceName) is now ($serviceBefore.status)...`r`n"

    Write-Host "Starting Windows Service ($serviceName)...`r`n"
    Start-Service $serviceName
    Write-Host "Successfully started Windows Service ($serviceName)...`r`n"

    $serviceAfter = Get-Service $serviceName
    Write-Host "($serviceName) is now ($($serviceAfter.status))...`r`n"
}
```

All fine with Start/Stop/Copy New Windows Service Dll's.
But when I try to remove old files after stopping service all of them is locked and I get error:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item ...\WindowsService\bin\Autofac.dll: Access to the path '...WindowsService\bin\Autofac.dll' is denied.
```

For all dll files.

May be need to uninstall/install service isnstead of stop/run? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. 
First thing: I run this script **after** installation windows service in stopped status and dll's already was in folder. And first run didn't produce any error. After second run I get the errors.
When I added waiting after stop service and before removing old dll's everything was well:

```
StopWindowsService $serviceName

Start-Sleep -s 5

RemoveFiles $servicePath 
CopyFiles $serviceBinPath $servicePath
StartWindowsService $serviceName
```

I think that it is because the files have not yet unlocked immediately after stopping service.

Thanks a lot. Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

Stopping Service should be enought.
Check the following:

1. You are using direct pathes to your files
2. The application or console that runs your script is running under properly priveledged user.
3. Check the dlls folder security. Check if the user your application running on is priveldged to delete files in the specified folder